# TFS Test runs reporting inconsistent count of tests run each build

Tags: tfs, vs-unit-testing-framework

Using the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.RunAgileTestRunner` activity that shipped with VS2013RTM, I have unit tests set up like this:

[image: Image of build definition]

When I run these builds, the tests run fine, however there are different results in the count being reported every time. Not only are the counts different between builds, but the Build Summary page for a given build run will also consistently shows different counts of tests than the actual test results (.trx) file.

I also tried the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.RunTests` activity, and I get the same issues with the test results described above. However, I am able to use its RunTestsTestCompletedEventArgs to write a build message of the name of the test followed by the result, and when I do this I see the same number of tests run each time, which means something is wrong with the summary report and/or the published results (right? **RIGHT???**):

[image: image of build summary results versus test results window]

Also, I have two assemblies with 'tests' in the name which get picked up by the filter, I know that this aspect is working because the bin folder on the build box will have same size on disk among all of the different runs which produce different results.

**So, what is going on with these numbers? What am I doing wrong in my build definition or on the build box that is causing this?**

Comment: are your missing 106 tests marked in a diffent category / NOT marked with a Test category?  Remove the filter "TestCategory=OnCheckin" and see what results you get

Comment: Even when I remove the TestCategory filter, I get varying results. For example, two runs at the same time gives me 4332 in build summary, 4553 in test results. Then an hour later, two runs at the same time give me 4557 in build summary, 4563 in test results. If I repeat this, I will get different results yet again

Comment: Having a very simliar problem - did anyone ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I have case open with Microsoft. So...in a few months if they get to bottom of it I'll let you know!

Comment: Same problem here, please post if you manage to figure something out.

Comment: I am facing similar problem, I've more than 2500 unit test in the solution and build result reports inconsistent unit test count, some times 128 and 150 and so on. I use VS2012, TFS2012 and nunit. Has anyone found the solution?

Comment: I got confirmation from Microsoft that they can repro the issue. I get the same inconsistencies through the vstest.console command line too. So..back to running tests in devenv.exe I guess!

Comment: Noteworthy: if you are adding tests in your commits which kick off the build, it could be that the summary won't reflect the true count until the next run (the next run without a test in a commit)